# 2 Column paragraph

Tags: css, multiple-columns, paragraph

I know it's not hard to do that but I want to know the best way to achieve this

[image]

In case of responsive the right part need to go above the left part for each item.

Basically we have something like his
1  2
3  4
5  6

And in responsive it cannot be
1
3
5
2
4
6

Is there a way to achieve this avoiding float elements?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: it's more of a table than a 2 column paragraph - you could try nesting each property and value in their own div. why do you not want floats?

Comment: This is absolutely the right place for a table....so why not use one? It's still allowed for tabular data.

Comment: @Paulie_D True! I can use table too ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

p span {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Stuff</span>HAHAHAH</p>
<p><span>Stuff</span>HAHAHAH</p>
<p><span>Stuff</span>HAHAHAH</p>
<p><span>Stuff</span>HAHAHAH</p>
<p><span>Stuffing stuff</span>HAHAHAH</p>
```

Comment: This one works well ! Thanks! Easy to change for responsive issues!